# Too much parameter in RNN

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras

I have 50 station which measure weather and pollution values (6 parameter per station) after doing one hot encoding on one column (wind direction) 8 new columns are added and the original removed. In the end I have 50 * 13 = 650 columns and 35000 record (each measurement is produced every hour, basically the last 4 years).
Giving all of this information to a model of a RNN made as follow, result in a crash caused by full use of hardware resources. I already splitted the data along the time through a TimeSeriesGenerator to create batch of 128 example of 24 hours each (so batch size is 128 and 24 is the sequence length).

Is there a way to compute the training, validation and testing, giving one station meausurements at a time (so batches with 13 columns per time)?  I know this couldn't be clear, feel free to ask more info...

```
all_data_generator = iter(TimeseriesGenerator(data = x_train_scaled, 
                                            targets = y_train_scaled, 
                                            length = sequence_length, 
                                            shuffle=False, 
                                            batch_size=(num_train - sequence_length + 1)))

train_data_x, train_data_y = next(all_data_generator)
train_data_size = train_data_x.shape[0]

validation_data_size = int(train_data_size * validation_split)
val_data_x = train_data_x[train_data_size-validation_data_size:]
val_data_y = train_data_y[train_data_size-validation_data_size:]

train_data_x = train_data_x[0:train_data_size-validation_data_size]
train_data_y = train_data_y[0:train_data_size-validation_data_size]
train_data_size = train_data_x.shape[0]


train_generator = getBatch(x = train_data_x, y = train_data_y, batch_size = batch_size)

validation_data = (val_data_x, val_data_y)
validation_generator = getBatch (x = val_data_x, y = train_data_y, batch_size = batch_size)

test_generator = iter(TimeseriesGenerator(data=x_test_scaled, 
                                          targets=y_test_scaled, 
                                          length= sequence_length, 
                                          shuffle=False, 
                                          batch_size=(num_test - sequence_length + 1)))

test_data_x, test_data_y = next(test_generator)
test_generator = getBatch(test_data_x, test_data_y, batch_size = batch_size)

 #### MODEL TYPE DECLARATION AND CONFIGURATION ######################################

code_name = {-1: "linear", 0: "ann_base_single", 1 : "ann_base_multi", 
             2 : "gru_single_layer", 3 : "gru_single_layer_w_dropout", 4 : "gru_multi_layer", 5 : "gru_multi_layer_2",
             6 : "gru_single_layer_w_state", 7 : "gru_single_layer_w_dropout_w_state", 8 : "gru_multi_layer_w_state", 9 : "gru_multi_2_w_state",
             10 : "lstm_single_layer", 11 : "lstm_single_layer_w_dropout", 12 : "lstm_multi_layer", 13 : "lstm_multi_layer_2",
             14 : "lstm_single_layer_w_state", 15 : "lstm_single_layer_w_dropout_w_state", 16 : "lstm_multi_layer_w_state", 17 : "lstm_multi_2_w_state", 18 : "test_conv"}
model_type = 5

model = Sequential()
if model_type == -1:
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='linear'))
elif model_type == 0:
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 1:
    model.add(layers.Flatten(input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 2:
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 3:
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 4:
    model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.GRU(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 5:
    model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.GRU(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(layers.GRU(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 6:
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 7:
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 8:
    model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.GRU(32, activation='relu', stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 9:
    model.add(layers.GRU(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.GRU(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.GRU(16, activation='relu', stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 10:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 11:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 12:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 13:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(16, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 14:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 15:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 16:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 17:
    model.add(layers.LSTM(64, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(batch_size, sequence_length, x_data.shape[1]), stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(32, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.LSTM(16, activation='relu', stateful=True))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))
elif model_type == 18:
    model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters= x_data.shape[1], kernel_size=1 , input_shape=(sequence_length, x_data.shape[1])))
    model.add(layers.GRU(hidden_layer_size, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(num_y_signals, activation='sigmoid'))


model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='mae', metrics=[metrics.mae, 'accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Running on a ASUS N550 with i7-4700HQ 8GB of ram

EDIT: this is the model summary

```
[5 rows x 713 columns]
Station    2000003                             ...               Time
Parameter        0        1             2      ...               H_21          H_22          H_23
count      43824.0  43824.0  43824.000000      ...       43824.000000  43824.000000  43824.000000
mean           0.0      0.0     25.085629      ...           0.041667      0.041667      0.041667
std            0.0      0.0     16.950108      ...           0.199829      0.199829      0.199829
min            0.0      0.0      1.000000      ...           0.000000      0.000000      0.000000
25%            0.0      0.0     11.000000      ...           0.000000      0.000000      0.000000
50%            0.0      0.0     21.000000      ...           0.000000      0.000000      0.000000
75%            0.0      0.0     35.000000      ...           0.000000      0.000000      0.000000
max            0.0      0.0    134.000000      ...           1.000000      1.000000      1.000000
```

Comment: If you are crashing due to hardware limitations I would suggest you add your specs to your question.

Comment: Added, even if I thinks the problem is that too many feature at the same time

Comment: Yep, definately. I assume you do not have a GPU you can use?

Can you also show your model.summary()?

Comment: Reduce the batch size, its the key driver for memory usage. Furthermore don´t use a notebook for deep learning :)

Comment: I know that a lapton isn't the best choice, but that is what I have ahah

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you only have 8 GB's of RAM this is probably going to be a difficult task for your current hardware.

I would start by stripping away as much as possible from your model and see if it can handle that, maybe start with removing your two center GRU layers.

You could als try to set a small batch size during your model.fit, 8,16 or 32 could be good numbers to start with.

Comment: I reduced the batch size, seem that the out of memory happens before the train, by the TimeSeries Generator.